# Java Spring Security hasAnyAuthority doesn't works

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-security

I have a spring restful application, backend - Spring 2.4.3, frontend - Angular, when I trying to restrict access to individual pages, I get 401 code. I've tried all variations of hasRole () and hasAuthority () nothing helps. What am I doing wrong?

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/profile","/profile/*").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN","INTERVIEWER")
            .antMatchers("/getAllUsers").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            /*.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)*/
            .cors();
}
```

Role.java

```
@XmlType
@XmlEnum
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ADMIN,
    USER,
    INTERVIEWER;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Результат :(]

something wrong :(

Comment: please update your question with the spring security debug logs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided code, the line `.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` is commented out. I can't speak to what happens when you un-comment that line (since it is a custom filter), but without that line, you have no means of authenticating. This results in your entry point (which is not provided in your example) being invoked, and seems to be returning your 401 status code.

You can test this by commenting out the lines:

```java
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
```

and adding `.formLogin().and()` instead. Form Login will provide a default authentication entry point, default authentication filter, and (if using spring boot) default user details service with a randomly generated password printed to your console, which you can use to test logging in. See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-hello-auto-configuration) for more info on this.

**A note** on testing with hello world (out of the box) configuration: It is a very useful technique to use `formLogin()` for testing authorization rules (e.g. `.antMatchers("/profile","/profile/*").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN","INTERVIEWER")`) in Spring Security. It allows you to eliminate your authentication mechanism from being the problem. Once you are confident your authorization rules are working, you can move on to configuring your own authentication scheme. When possible, seek to utilize an existing scheme provided by Spring Security, and only create a custom filter when you cannot use an out of the box scheme. You can read about [JWT authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture) in the docs.